# What is the best or common terms to describe students affairs and activities?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice

I am looking for a word or phrase that can be used to represent or include all students affairs or activities. I want to provide an online service for students such as (and/or including) student enrolments, payments and records keeping, etc.

I have thought of the Student Office, Student Registry and Student Records but unsure of the best to use. Many thanks.

Comment: On EL&U, requests for words or phrases should include some textual context. It doesn't need to be a work of art, but it should be something more extensive than a heading. A sentence or paragraph with "___" as a placeholder would be fine.

Comment: Your own examples (Student Office, Student Registry and Student Records) are all fine, really. Some places use "Student Affairs" or "Student Services". There is no one right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe say the student **hub**

A definition of hub:

> the effective centre of an activity, region, or network.

I feel like this my apply to you. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, @Wool, yes, indeed. Does the term hub has any connotation on the informality in usage? For example, would one expect to go the Student Hub to make payment for the course enrolment? I guess it could be just different perspectives for different people.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a **Bursar's Office**.

> [Bursar](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bursar): A person who manages the financial affairs of a college or school.

Typically a bursar will also hold all the students records because the first thing they check before any information is released is if you have paid the tuition fees!

Comment: Thanks, I learned a new word :) I think the scope is limited to financial only.